# Decode JSON string containing JSON string

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have to decode a JSON string containing another JSON string on it. Currently I'm trying to decode it into a `Dictionary<string,string>` using `Serializator.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(value)` from `System.Web.Script.Serialization`, but haven't succeed.

This is the string:

```
{
      "label": "Side",
      "options": [
        {
          "key": "left",
          "value": 0
        },
        {
          "key": "right",
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
}
```

And this is the format error I get from the decoder:

> (System.ArgumentException HResult=0x80070057 Message=Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (34): {"label": "Side", "options": "[{"key": "left", "value": 0},{"key":"right", "value":1}]"} Source=System.Web.Extensions) 
>   Which means he gets "[{" as a string and thus fails to convert of course...

Is there any way I can decode this specific JSON string and store it in an object? Client is very specific about this JSON format... Thanks a lot

Comment: Seems like a pain that you are receiving invalid json......

Comment: You may have to pre-parse the json into something that can be passed to a deserialiser.

Comment: There is a link to jsonlint In the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/json/info). It is a good tool for validation and formatting.

Comment: JSON string is not valid. Please get it corrected using jsonlint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Represent your `json` like that:

```
{
  "label": "Side",
  "options": "[{ 'key': 'left', 'value': '0'},{ 'key':'right', 'value':1}]"
}
```

*inside json with single quotes*

let's assume you have this two classes :

```
public class YourObject
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string options { get; set; }
    }
    public class InsideObject
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
    }
```

so your json has another json as as string under the key *"options"* and you can extract both of them like that:

```
 string json = "{\"label\": \"Side\", \"options\": \"[{ 'key': 'left', 'value': '0'},{ 'key':'right', 'value':1}]\"}";
 var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(json);
 var insideObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InsideObject>(jsonObj.options);
```

**P.S**
here used [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: Doesn't work... as soon as it gets to the first single cuote, the deserializer thinks that's the end of the string and throws an error because it is an invalid way of ending a JSON string

Comment: Proposing to _Represent your `json` like that_ (and storing an object in form of a string) is in my opinion on the same level as using _Object_ everywhere :D

Comment: I agree with you. I just answered his his question: "...string containing another JSON string on it".

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used string format as follows:

```
{
  "label": "Side",
  "options": [
    {
      "key": "left",
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "key": "right",
      "value": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

and store all the **JSON** in a `Dictionary< string, object >`. I will then implement a method to decode the object inside the **JSON**.

Answer (score -1):

As Matt already mentioned in his comment your JSON is invalid, instead of `"[{"key"` it should be `[{"key"` and instead of `}]"}` it should be `}]}`.

Comment: I have no problems with down votes at all as long as I can learn something from them (which is not possible without any comment).