# How to deserialize raw json field to model using Newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

So my json data is coming as string like following:

```
    { "name":"aaa", "sub": "{"x":"sss", "y":"eee"}" }
```

Sub field is a raw json string here.

My model is like following.

```
    class Main
    {
        public string Name { get;set;}
        public Sub Sub { get;set;}
    }

    class Sub
    {
        public string X { get;set;}
        public string Y { get;set;}
    }
```

I want to deserialize it like following:

```
var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); // getting data.
var jsonString = JsonConvert.Deseialize(response).ToString(); // to string.
var model = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Main>(jsonString); // error
```

The last step throws exception, like "string can not cast to Main" class.

Comment: Well Sub is a string. have  a `public string Sub { get;set;}`. And a other properties that get populated by desializing the string once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decode JSON string containing JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061812/decode-json-string-containing-json-string)

Comment: First of all, that isn't valid JSON. Perhaps you meant to escape the nested double quotes?

Comment: May I ask why there is encoded JSON within a JSON payload and why its not just a JSON object within a parent field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your question has a typo and you meant to escape the double quotes, e.g.:

```
{ "name":"aaa", "sub": "{\"x\":\"sss\", \"y\":\"eee\"}" }
```

Then you can achieve this with a custom converter. For example:

```
public class NestedJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => true;

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
        object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Get the raw string
        var s = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);

        // Deserialise into the correct type
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s, objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
            => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

And change your model to add the attribute:

```
class Main
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NestedJsonConverter))]
    public Sub Sub { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can simply deserialise like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Main>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other Answers, you need a 2-Step deserialization.However, if you do not want to introduce a Custom JsonConverter, you could introduce a new property in the Main class which could assist in deserialization. For example,

```
class Main
{
    public string Name { get;set;}

    private string _subString;
    [JsonProperty("Sub")]
    public string SubString {
        get => _subString;
        set
        {
            _subString = value;
            Sub = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sub>(_subString);
        }
    }
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Sub Sub { get;set;}
}

class Sub
{
    public string X { get;set;}
    public string Y { get;set;}
}
```

The `Sub` property would not be assigned during initial deserializing (step 1), instead, when the `SubString` property is assigned, it would make another call to Deserialize the string value and assign the `Sub` property.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a 2-step deserialization.  If the value of `sub` is a string then it's a string, not a `Sub` instance.  That string may be a JSON representation of a `Sub` instance, but that's another deserialization altogether.

First deserialize into the type represented by the whole object:

```
class Main
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public string Sub { get;set; }
}
```

and:

```
var mainObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Main>(response);
```

Then `mainObj.Sub` would contain the JSON string for your next type:

```
class Sub
{
    public string X { get;set; }
    public string Y { get;set; }
}
```

Which you can deserialize the same way:

```
var subObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sub>(mainObj.Sub);
```

Overall the process of deserializing a JSON string to an object is the same.  You just have to do it twice when you have two JSON strings.